# Need Fingerprint Driver for Lenovo Thinkbook 15

Tags: drivers, lenovo, open-source

Fingerprint was working fine when using Windows 11 but once switched to Ubuntu the Fingerprint sensor was not working. I searched through the Internet an Goodix as well as Lenovo Website for Fingerprint Driver, but couldn't find one.

Fingerprint Sensor Details : ID 27c6:55a4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by Linux as of now.

Statement from LHDB:

> Goodix fingerprint devices are known to lack drivers due to Goodix' reluctance to officially support Linux. An unofficial driver for fprintd is currently being worked on.

https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:27c6-55a4&page=1#status